# Updating banned word string from query to match

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to query from the database words at set interval and match them against Twitter API, I can't figure out how to the the variable

```
var bannedName = rows[0].name;
```

into this expression, right now just placing bannedName variable would result undentified

```
if(!tweetTextRetweet.match(/^RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT/))
```

to result like

```
if(!tweetTextRetweet.match(bannedName))
```

In order to have it work and match against the word. If I put the query outside interval It does not update the query leaving the result unmodified when changed in database

Here's what I currently have

```
setInterval(function() {

    con.query("SELECT setting,name FROM droid_settings WHERE ID = 2", function(error,rows){ 
        var bannedName = rows[0].name;
        console.log('INFO ------- ',bannedName);

    });

    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        var tweetTextRetweet = tweets[i].text; 

        if (!tweetTextRetweet.match(/^RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT/)) { // search for RT and @
            console.log('INFO -------',tweets[i].id);
            dateTime(); 
            console.log('INFO -------',tweets[i].text);


            tweets.length = 0;
        }else{
            //console.log('SKIPPED');
            //dateTime(); 
        }

    }
    // reset the tweets array
    tweets.length = 0;
},  4 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straighforward way is to just add a second condition to your `if` statement:

```
if (tweetTextRetweet.indexOf(bannedName) !== -1 && !tweetTextRetweet.match(/^RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT/)) {
```

You can also put the bannedName into the regex, but you have to construct the regex from a string with the regex constructor to do so and you have to make sure that `bannedName` does not contain any special regex matching characters that are not properly escaped (that's why I used `.indexOf()` above because it isn't sensitive to regex characters in `bannedName` so the name doesn't have to be escaped.

Assuming `bannedName` does not contain any special regex characters, the regex could be built dynamically like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(bannedName + "|^RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT");
if (!regex.test(tweetTextRetweet)) {
```

If you need to escape possible regex characters in `bannedName`, you can use a function from this answer to do so: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

---

Maybe I first misunderstood your question.  If you want to use the `bannedName` from the query, then just put the rest of your code inside the function where `bannedName` is available.

```
setInterval(function() {

    con.query("SELECT setting,name FROM droid_settings WHERE ID = 2", function(error,rows){ 
        var bannedName = rows[0].name;
        console.log('INFO ------- ',bannedName);

        for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
            var tweetTextRetweet = tweets[i].text; 

            if (tweetTextRetweet.indexOf(bannedName) === -1 && !tweetTextRetweet.match(/^RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT/)) { // search for RT and @
                console.log('INFO -------',tweets[i].id);
                dateTime(); 
                console.log('INFO -------',tweets[i].text);


                tweets.length = 0;
            }else{
                //console.log('SKIPPED');
                //dateTime(); 
            }

        }
        // reset the tweets array
        tweets.length = 0;
    });

},  4 * 1000);
```

Comment: yes but If I put bannedName outside query it's undentify that's what I asked

Comment: ReferenceError: bannedName is not defined

Comment: @Alex_TNT - see what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Current example will match against database or the match string?

Comment: @Alex_TNT - if you need to change the logic of the `if` feel free to edit when incorporating in your code.  I think I've answered your main question and perhaps didn't understand exactly which logic you wanted in the `if` statement, but you can fix that yourself, right?

Comment: I wanted !tweetTextRetweet.match(bannedName) if I make it this way it does not work, your example works, bannedName = /^RT|RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT/g   in database

Comment: To answer you question, no I think I'm over my head... don't really know where the problem lies and how to fix it further, might be like you said I need to escape regex characters, I think, not really sure but match() method has the exact format string...

Comment: Nevermind seems the problem was with the API stream. Thank you again